# Vertical List from string array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

```
render(){
        const { data } = this.props

        const newArray = data.abs.map((abs, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: abs.event.toString, start: abs.times, title: abs.trs, end: null}) )


        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');


          return(              

            <div className="timeline">
                <Timeline 
                    //groups={groups}
                    items={nArray}
                    options={options}
                    container={container}


                  />;

            </div>
          )//return

      }//render
```

The above displays the results as: `["item1","item2","itme3"]`. However, I would like this:

```
item1,
item2,
item3
```

I tried `.split()` but React is saying `.split()` is not a function.  I also tried `JSON.stringify(abs.event, null 2)` but it does work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither of your questions are particularly clear. You need to write a [mcve] with an example of your input data, your expected output, and the code you've used to try to solve the issue.

Comment: `.split()` is a String method, not an Array method.

Comment: This is example is saying it is, hence my confusion: https://alligator.io/js/split-string-method/

Comment: Here is another using .split() with an array: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/splitting-an-array-trying-to-use-reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your results displays as : `["item1","item2","itme3"]`

Once try: `["item1","item2","itme3"].join(",<br>");`

it may help you.